# How to get android:launchMode attribute in program code

Tags: android, launchmode

I need to dismiss my dialog if the `android:launchMode` is not `standard`, I need to access this attribute in my code, it is set in the manifest file, I cannot find the solution, anyone can help? Thank you!

Comment: what do you want to do which depends on launch mode? tell me so that i can help

Comment: For example I have a dialogFragment shown in the activity, and if the launch mode is standard, Android will create a new window to show another intent, and the dialog should be retained, and if the mode is singleTask, the dialog needs to be dismisses to show another intent content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in general, if activity launchMode is not `standard` you open activity it will call `onNewIntent`, or it will call `onCreate`. hope it helps you.

Comment: activity default launch mode is "standard"

Comment: It is an acceptable solution and it works, thank you! But I wonder whether there is a easier way.

Comment: @newszer if it works it should be accepted. is there an easier way? now i have no idea, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If launch mode is **"singleTask"** it will come to onNewIntent if you are launching same activity again otherwise for first time it will call onCreate.

you can safely write your code inside **onNewIntent**

Comment: I think it is same solution as jame

Answer (score 0):

You can try 'getIntent().getFlags()'

[image]

Comment: I try it and its value is also 0.